# Emulator not opening in Visual Studio for Xamarin mobile app development

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2019, emulation, windows-8.1, hyper-v

I am trying to develop a mobile app using Xamarin and Visual Studio 2019 on a Windows 8.1 Pro operating system. I installed the .NET desktop development, ASP.NET and web development, and Mobile development with .NET workloads, and I am trying to run the Pixel 2 Pie 9.0 - API 28 emulator in Visual Studio.

When I try to launch the emulator through the Android Device Manager, I get the following error:

> Device error: WARNING: unexpected '-prop' value ('monodroid.avdname=pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28'), only 'qemu.' properties are supported WARNING: unexpected '-prop' value ('emu.uuid=a7af4d97-19e3-499d-9c26-334ea3d7cfe0'), only 'qemu.' properties are supported

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy10C.png)

When I try to launch the emulator through the green triangle at the top of the Visual Studio user interface, I get the following performance warning:

> Performance Warning: Launching the Android Emulator pixel 2 pie 90-api_28 on Hyper-V needs Windows Spring Creators Update (Redstone 4) or newer installed. Please update your system and retry.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXSbA.png)

My laptops

> OS : Windows 8.1 pro
>
> 64-bit Operating System
>
> Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-5005U CPU @ 2.00GHz
>
> RAM : 4.00 GB
>
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLOp7.png)

I went through Android Device Manager and edited the emulator I had installed. There I changed its name and processor to x86_64 instead of x86 and downloaded it. Then I restarted the computer and ran the emulator.  But there also the same double error message as mentioned earlier, no difference. My data is limited so I didn't waste it on more guesswork. But I will gladly accept any of your recommendations

I want to solve the above problems under this operating system. I am currently unable to upgrade my operating system to Windows 10 or 11. I want to work in Visual Studio with minimal error messages. Having to use another emulator or old technology is not a problem there.

What could be causing these errors, and how can I resolve them? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Although not directly related to this, I will mention the following issues.

- When I installed the emulator in Visual Studio Xamarin I got a prompt to install intel HAXM. But its automatic installation failebd and I downloaded and installed it manually from Intel website there. After that I got the two errors in the screenshot above.
- When doing that I had installed both the latest version of Visual Studio 2022 and this 2019 version.  (I was able to install both in Windows 8.1 Pro) Then I uninstalled the 2022 version.
- Also, even though I installed it under the update I received for version 16.11.25 of Visual Studio, over a day later, It's not updated in the Visual Studio installer or the versioned install in the IDE.
- And in my Visual Studio installer, above the Modify button, under Total Space Required , 13MB of non-removable space is noted. I have run the Modify button  several times but it won't go away. (That may have something to do with the note "System cache, tools, and SDKs with fixed locations - 13 MB" on the Installation locations tab in the installer.)
- When opening ASP.NET and wed development and Mobile development with .NET (out of support) workloads for the first time, the nuget.org package source was not included in the package sources by default. So the packages got errors. I then solved the problem by adding the nuget.org package to the source.

Comment: I unticked Hyper-V through the control panel and restarted the computer, where the emulator opened without error messages. But it takes a long time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this [Hardware acceleration for emulator performance (Hyper-V & HAXM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows) for more information.

In this article, you can see the minimum criterion of the `Hyper-V`.
Your computer hardware must meet the following requirements:

- A 64-bit Intel or AMD Ryzen CPU with Second Level Address Translation
  (SLAT).
- CPU support for VM Monitor Mode Extension (VT-c on Intel CPUs).
- Minimum of 4-GB memory.
- Virtualization Technology (may have a different label depending on
  motherboard manufacturer).
- Hardware Enforced Data Execution Prevention.
- Verify that the Windows Version is at least 1803

To verify that your computer hardware and software is compatible with Hyper-V, open a command prompt and type the following command: `systeminfo`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems my Windows 8.1 Pro system does not support this.

Answer (score 0):

I unticked Hyper-V through the control panel and restarted the computer, where the emulator opened without error messages. But it takes a long time

Comment: Looking at this answer and your question I think you meant this as additional information. In the future you can add that information with an edit to your question, or a comment on your question.

Comment: Ok, I submitted it as a comment as well. thank you..